# convert dask.bag of dictionaries to dask.dataframe using dask.delayed and pandas.DataFrame

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

I am struggling to convert a `dask.bag` of dictionaries into `dask.delayed` `pandas.DataFrames` into a final `dask.dataframe`

I have one function (make_dict) that reads files into a rather complex nested dictionary structure and another function (make_df) to turn these dictionaries into a `pandas.DataFrame` (resulting dataframe is around 100 mb for each file). I would like to append all dataframes into a single `dask.dataframe` for further analysis.

Up to now I was using `dask.delayed` objects to load, convert and append all data which works fine (see example below). However for future work I would like to store the loaded dictionaries in a `dask.bag` using `dask.persist()`.

I managed to load the data into `dask.bag`, resulting in a list of dicts or list of `pandas.DataFrame` that I can use locally after calling `compute()`. When I tried turning the `dask.bag` into a `dask.dataframe` using `to_delayed()` however, I got stuck with an error (see below).

It feels like I am missing something rather simple here or maybe my approach to `dask.bag` is wrong?

The below example shows my approach using simplified functions and throws the same error. Any advice on how to tackle this is appreciated.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe
import dask.bag

print(dask.__version__) # 1.1.4
print(pd.__version__) # 0.24.2

def make_dict(n=1):
    return {"name":"dictionary","data":{'A':np.arange(n),'B':np.arange(n)}}

def make_df(d):
    return pd.DataFrame(d['data'])

k = [1,2,3]

# using dask.delayed
dfs = []
for n in k:
    delayed_1 = dask.delayed(make_dict)(n)
    delayed_2 = dask.delayed(make_df)(delayed_1)
    dfs.append(delayed_2)
ddf1 = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(dfs).compute() # this works as expected

# using dask.bag and turning bag of dicts into bag of DataFrames
b1 = dask.bag.from_sequence(k).map(make_dict)
b2 = b1.map(make_df)

df = pd.DataFrame().append(b2.compute()) # <- I would like to do this using delayed dask.DataFrames like above
ddf2 = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(b2.to_delayed()).compute() # <- this fails

# error:
# ValueError: Expected iterable of tuples of (name, dtype), got [   A  B
# 0  0  0]
```

what I ultimately would like to do using the distributed scheduler:

```py
b = dask.bag.from_sequence(k).map(make_dict)
b = b.persist()
ddf = dask.dataframe.from_delayed(b.map(make_df).to_delayed())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bag case the delayed objects point to lists of elements, so you have a list of lists of pandas dataframes, which is not quite what you want.  Two recommendations

1. Just stick with dask.delayed.  It seems to work well for you
2. Use the [Bag.to_dataframe](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.to_dataframe) method, which expects a bag of dicts, and does the dataframe conversion itself

Comment: Thanks, I went with option 1 and just made the delayed dictionaries persist on the distributed system which gave me pretty much what I wanted (I thought using bag might be easier but delayed serves me just as well here).

I will look into bag.to_dataframe as well though, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: When you have the list of lists of pandas dataframe - can we just flatten the list ourselves then pass it to dask.dataframe.from_delayed?

Comment: Yes.  As long as you deliver a list of delayed objects of pandas dataframes you should be ok.  Dask doesn't care how you use Python to create that list.