# Dict to dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a list of dictionaries of `delayed`. The computed value of each `delayed` object has to turn into an entry in the `dask.Dataframe`.

```
dfs = []

for source_list in list_of_list:
    values1 = {}
    values2 = {}

    for source in source_list:
        intermediate = dask.delayed(myfunc)(source)

        source_name = string_manipulation(source)
        values1[source_name] = dask.delayed(myfunc1)(intermediate)
        values2[source_name] = dask.delayed(myfunc2)(intermediate)

    df1 = dd.from_delayed(values1)  # TypeError: Expected Delayed object, got str
    df2 = dd.from_delayed(values2)
    df = dd.concat(df1, df2)
    df = df.T  # transpose function for dd?
    dfs.append(df)

dfs = dd.concat(dfs)
dfs = dfs.compute()
```

Normally `pandas.DataFrame` converts the key of a dictionary to columns. How can this be achieved in `dask.DataFrame`? Perhaps there are more efficient methods.

I appreciate your comment.

Comment: I think this has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59377561/create-a-dask-dataframe-from-a-dictionary

Comment: I think the difference comes from the delayed object as the dictionary element. Is there a way to compute only after `dask.DataFrame` is created for more efficient computation?

Answer (score 0):

dd.from_delayed expects a list of delayed objects, each of which returns a pandas dataframe.  You are providing a dictionary of delayed objects, hence the error.

You need to create a list of delayed objects, each of which would produce a pandas dataframe when computed.  All of those pandas dataframes should have identical columns and types.